# Getting the following error when assigning float value to an array: ("'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment", 'occurred at index 4')

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting the error 
TypeError: ("'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment", 'occurred at index 4')
when I attempt to assign values to elements in my numpy array sequentially. The value I'm attempting to assign to the element is a float so I have no idea what's going on.

My function is as follows:

```
def get_next_month_data(data):
    next_month_data = np.zeros(data.shape, dtype=float)
    data = data.values
    row_index = 0

    #SellerAccountID
    next_month_data[row_index] = data[0]
    row_index += 1

    #CurrentBalance
    if data[8] == 1:
        next_month_data = data[1]
    else:
        next_month_data[row_index] = data[1] - (data[8] - data[1] * data[2])
    row_index += 1

    #calculated_rate

    next_month_data[row_index] = data[2]
    row_index += 1

    #contractual_payment_propensity
    next_month_data[row_index] = data[3]
    row_index += 1

    #arrears increase propensity
    next_month_data[row_index] = data[4]
    row_index += 1

    #arrears decrease propensity
    next_month_data[row_index] = data[5]
    row_index += 1

    #Number
    next_month_data[row_index] = data[6]
    row_index += 1

    #pay_amnt
    next_month_data[row_index] = 0
    row_index += 1

    #default flag
    if data[9] < 6 and data[8] != 1:
        next_month_data[row_index] = 0
    else:
        next_month_data[row_index] = 1
    row_index += 1

    #months in arrears
    if data[7] == 0:
        next_month_data[row_index] = data[9] + 1
    elif data[7] == data[10]:
        next_month_data[row_index] = data[9]
    else:
        next_month_data[row_index] = data[9] - 1
    row_index += 1

    #repayment value
    next_month_data[row_index] = data[10]
    row_index += 1

    return next_month_data
```

The argument data is a pandas series. The error is always thrown at the line

```
next_month_data[row_index] = data[2]
```

All elements in my series are float values.

Please help this is so frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Could the culprit be the following lines?

```py
if data[8] == 1:
    next_month_data = data[1]
```

Shouldn't it be `next_month_data[row_index] = data[1]`?